# how to retrieve the column values which are aggregated(like count) using groupby column

Tags: group-by, postgresql-9.1

I want to display the contents of the aggregated columns that is part of group by sql statement.
Example:

```
SELECT Shippers.ShipperName,COUNT(Orders.OrderID) AS NumberOfOrders FROM Orders
WHERE Orders.ShipperID=Shippers.ShipperID
GROUP BY ShipperName
```

In the above example the output gives me count as one of the result, whereas i need the aggregated orders.orderID actual values even. So say if one result count shows me 2. I need to know what are those two values which have been grouped. This result should be as another column in the same table.

Answer (score 0):

try this with `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
 SELECT Shippers.ShipperName,COUNT(Orders.OrderID) AS NumberOfOrders , array_agg(Orders.OrderID) as which_are_those FROM Orders
 WHERE Orders.ShipperID=Shippers.ShipperID
 GROUP BY ShipperName
```

array_agg returns an array, but you can CAST that to text and edit as needed (see clarifications, below).

Prior to version 8.4, you have to define it yourself prior to use:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE array_agg (anyelement)
(
sfunc = array_append,
stype = anyarray,
initcond = '{}'
);
```

or simply  this:

```
SELECT Shippers.ShipperName,COUNT(Orders.OrderID) AS NumberOfOrders , string_agg(Orders.OrderID, ',') as which_are_those FROM Orders
 WHERE Orders.ShipperID=Shippers.ShipperID
 GROUP BY ShipperName
```

Comment: the above statement throws an error as shown here "Undefined function 'GROUP_CONCAT' in expression."